# Chain generation of two graphs together

Tags: r

I'm trying to store a distribution and QQ plot side by side. If I run the lines at the same time by selecting them I see the graph how I would like it to be. If I try to run it chained and store it in the variable it will fail.

Error:

```
Error in par(mfrow = c(1, 2)) + hist(real_estate_db$debt, main = "Left Skewed Distribution",  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Code:

```
graph_debt <- par(mfrow=c(1,2)) +
  hist(real_estate_db$debt, main="Left Skewed Distribution", xlab="Debt", col="#FA5858") +
  qqnorm(real_estate_db$debt, col="blue") +
  qqline(real_estate_db$debt, col="red")
```

How can I store this in a variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html

```
library(dplyr)
library(cowplot)
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

plot_grid(p1, p2, labels = c('A', 'B'), label_size = 12)
```